# Simulating F11 key in C in linux

Tags: c

I need to know how to simulate the F11 key, which toggles the gnome-terminal's console window to full screen in Linux.

The OS I am using Linux Mint 14 (based on Ubuntu 12.10) and using gcc compiler.  The program is written in C

I have looked for this in other places but it is most things are for windows.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate the F11 key" and "the console"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Note that `gnome-terminal` (Ubuntu's default X terminal emulator) has a command-line option `--full-screen` which does what you'd think.

Comment: Under many window managers and/or applications, the F11 key is "toggle fullscreen". In other words, OP is asking how to programmatically go fullscreen, but not doing a very good job of asking.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Are you trying to control the behavior of another window/application where you literally need to send an F11 key code?  Or are you trying to have your application create a new full-screen window?  Or are you trying to run a program in an existing window, and then resize that window?  Is this a terminal window in X11 or the Linux text console?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself better. I am asking how to go full screen programmatically.  I wrote a program that I think will look better in full screen.  The program is a console program. I was thinking that if I simulated an F11 keystroke that it would do the trick.

Comment: You can't force a terminal emulator to go fullscreen. That's not a thing you can do. Instead, you should make sure your program works on terminals with at least 24 rows and 80 columns, which I believe is the size of a VT100 terminal display.

Comment: Is this a terminal emulator or the gnome terminal? I thought the gnome terminal could be made full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize many terminals (from within the terminal) by using the escape sequence:

> <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> height <kbd>;</kbd> width <kbd>t</kbd>

In C, this would look like:

```
printf("\e[4;%d;%dt", height, width);
```

There's no straightforward way to determine the maximum usable size.